# Is there is way to replace this preprocessor macro with a template, perhaps using Boost MPL?

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor

I have code that makes it possible to create a character or string constant that can be either of type char or wchar_t. This makes it possible to create template functions that work with either character type an yet use character or string constants. The solution I have come with so far is as follows.

```
template<typename CharType>
CharType CharConstantOfType(const char c, const wchar_t w);
template<>
char CharConstantOfType<char>(const char c, const wchar_t /*w*/)
{
    return c;
}
template<>
wchar_t CharConstantOfType<wchar_t>(const char /*c*/, const wchar_t w)
{
    return w;
}

template<typename CharType>
const CharType* StringConstantOfType(const char* c, const wchar_t* w);
template<>
const char* StringConstantOfType<char>(const char* c, const wchar_t* /*w*/)
{
    return c;
}
template<>
const wchar_t* StringConstantOfType<wchar_t>(const char* /*c*/, const wchar_t* w)
{
    return w;
}
```

These template functions require you to duplicate the constant by supplying both versions of the constant. To fix these problems I created the following macros.

```
#define _TOWSTRING(x) L##x
#define TOWSTRING(x) _TOWSTRING(x)
#define CHAR_CONSTANT(TYPE, STRING) CharConstantOfType<TYPE>(STRING, TOWSTRING(STRING))
#define STRING_CONSTANT(TYPE, STRING) StringConstantOfType<TYPE>(STRING, TOWSTRING(STRING))
```

I would like to eliminate the macros. I was wondering if something like the Boost MPL library could make this possible.

One possible use of these macros is to write a template function that determines whether or not a string contains a tab character, as follows.

```
template<typename CharType>
bool hasTab(const std::basic_string<CharType>& str)
{
    typedef std::basic_string<CharType> string_type;
    const CharType TabChar =  CHAR_CONSTANT(CharType, '\t');
    return (str.find(TabChar) != string_type::npos);
}
```

Comment: I don't think templates allow you to create a string literal out of another at compile-time if that's what you want. But I might be mistaken (if that's the case, I'd be interested in knowing how it's done).

Comment: +Caninonos What I want to do is to create a single string literal that can be either char or wchar_t.

Comment: Is there anything yoi can't do with a `char` literal which is possible with a `wchar_t` literal?

Comment: n.m.: Pass it to a function which takes a wchar_t argument? (You can widen a char to a wchar_t, but that doesn't guarantee that they represent the same *character*, just the same integer.)

Comment: @rici I mean at compile time.

Comment: @BenKey You can't have a *single* string literal which is either of type char or `wchar_t`. What you can do however (and what you are doing) is creating two string literals (containing the same text) with different types (the difference is that, if you use both, both versions will be stored in the data segment). You can't really do otherwise here as a `const char*` can't be interpreted safely as a `const wchar_t*` at runtime. At best, you can widen each char to a `wchar_t` (as rici states) but there's no way around making a copy of your original string (either at compile-time or at runtime).

Comment: Literals are tokens, sequences of characters in a source program. You cannot create a literal with a template, this makes no sense. Do you really need compile-time conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I had a little think about it. I don't think there is a valid conversion from wchar_t to char but the other way around is reasonable.

Here's a way to do it that allows you to only write the char* versions and allow the program to create the wchar_t strings as required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

// introduce the concept of a specialisable converter
template<class FromType, class ToType>
struct converter;

// use the concept
template<class To, class From>
To convert(From f) {
    return converter<From, To>::apply(f);
}

// specialise for non-conversion
template<class T>
struct converter<T, T>
{
    static constexpr T apply(T t) {
        return t;
    }
};

// specialise for converting char to wchar_t
template<>
struct converter<char, wchar_t>
{
    static constexpr wchar_t apply(char t) {
        // do whatever conversion you want here
        return wchar_t(t);
    }
};

// specialise for converting const char* to const wchar_t*
// note - this one is not thread-safe. a mutex will be needed to beef it up in a multi-
// threaded environment
template<>
struct converter<const char*, const wchar_t*>
{
    using string_map_type = std::map<const char*, std::wstring>;
    static string_map_type& string_map() {
        static string_map_type _;
        return _;
    }

    static std::wstring convert_to_wstring(const char*p ) {
        std::wstring result;
        while (*p) {
            result.push_back(convert<wchar_t>(*p++));
        }
        return result;
    }

    static const wchar_t* apply(const char* p) {
        auto& map = string_map();
        auto ifind = map.find(p);
        if (ifind == std::end(map)) {
            ifind = map.emplace(p, convert_to_wstring(p)).first;
        }
        return ifind->second.c_str();
    }
};


using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
    wcout << convert<const wchar_t*>("Hello, World") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
Hello, World
Hello, World
```